# I wanna make eco bot on discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, eco, sqlite3-python

**CODE**

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3
from config import settings

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'], intents = discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""") 

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None :
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0,0,1)")
            else:
                pass
        connection.commit()
        print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None :
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0,0,1)")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass

@bot.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None: 
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"""Баланс **{ctx.author}** короче **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"""Баланс **{member}** короче **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]}**"""
        ))


class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label="Balance", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def menu1(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.responce.send_message("""**Твой баланс короче ['balance']**""")
        
@bot.command
async def menu(ctx):
    view = Menu()
    await ctx.reply(view=view)



bot.run(settings['token'])
```

i wanna make menu with buttons "balance" "games" "profile" menu like this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/953166970763767868/1083399998139531334/image.png
but idk how make buttons to bot write ur balance, or profile with avatar
or maybe need go to js?

I tried to write something to guides on various topics with my underdeveloped brains

Comment: There's literally 0 reason to ever go to JS or vice-versa. Dpy can do everything supported by the discord API.

Answer (score 0):

There are official examples for Buttons that you could look at.. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples%2Fviews

The menu above is just a basic embed. Adding their profile picture is trivial because you get their User instance when they invoke the command.

The button callback has access to the user that invoked it, so you can get their ID from there to edit their bank.